# Higher z-index is not appearing above element

Tags: html, css

```
#navbarContentHamburger {
    background-image: url(../img/657904-64.png);
    background-size: contain;
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
    width: 22px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 7.7px;
    left:8px;
}

.open {
    width: 4% !important;
    transition: 0.4s;
    z-index: 2;
}

#sidebar {
    transition: 0.4s;
position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #0f9494;
    grid-area: navbar;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

I need this HTML element navbarContentHamburger to appear above ".open" and #sidebar, even if I change the z-index to higher than the rest, it will not go above at all and I cannot seem to figure it out

The idea is that I have a blue navbar with a white menu icon, when the icon is clicked, a div will cover the page with the new nav + the white icon(navbarContentHamburger) still in the corner.

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="navcontainer">
        <div id="navbarContent">
            <div id="navbarContentHamburger" @click="toggleMenu()">

            </div>
            <div id="navbarContentMenu">
                    <h4>MENU</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did the suggestion below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing all the right things, but your CSS don't have access to the image in the parent directory. Try specifying an absolute path to your hamburger icon image file. Here's an example:

```css
#navbarContentHamburger {
    background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-256.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 3;
    position: fixed;
    width: 22px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px
}

.open {
    width: 4% !important;
    transition: 0.4s;
    z-index: 2;
}

#sidebar {
    transition: 0.4s;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #0f9494;
    grid-area: navbar;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="navcontainer">
        <div id="navbarContent">
            <div id="navbarContentHamburger" @click="toggleMenu()">

            </div>
            <div id="navbarContentMenu">
                    <h4>MENU</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```